# std::tr1::function - store function objects of various types in common container

Tags: c++, function, std, functor, c++98

I'm converting my implementation of functor to `std::tr1::function` (the reason is that with my implementation we need to predefine type and functor class for each function type, I want to extend this to work with any function).

I have

```
int param = 1;
std::tr1::bind (&MyClass::func, param);
```

and I want to add this to some common container

```
someContainer.insert (std::tr1::bind (&MyClass::func, param));
```

so, how to declare the container, what type it must be to accept function of any type? Is it possible at all?

The second question - how to invoke functions in container, like this:

```
someContainer.begin().invoke();
```

P.S. Maybe there is another solution, I'm not aware enough in this topic. Would be thankful for answers.

I deal with GNU C++98.

Answer (score 1):

If by "any type" you mean all function objects (functors) having the same signature, then it's easy:

```
std::vector< std::tr1::function<void()> >  someContainer;
```

This will create a vector of any function objects that takes no parameters and returns void.

To invoke the function, just call it like a regular function object:

```
(*someContainer.begin()) ();
```